# saving content editable html for Google Earth application

Tags: html, google-earth

I just started working with html, and I am creating balloon description templates for Google Earth. I am creating site logs for gps locations around the world, and these sites get updated every now and then with a new receiver or antenna.

I have a table set up with all the information about the equipment we have at these sites, and I want to be able to change values in the table when the equipment is changed.
Right now the only way to do that is to go into the html code and find the specific value you need to change and then save the new html code. This works, but it would be nice if I could edit the values without having to go into the code. I know you can do `contenteditable=true` and then have some text you can edit, but when you refresh the page it goes back to the orignal text.

My question is if there is a way to edit the html code permanently without actually going through all the lines of code to find the one thing you want to change. If this cannot be done, or if my question makes no sense let me know. I probably just need to work with this stuff for more than a week.